# Why isnt collision detection working? (p5 js frame work)

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I created a collision detection between Snake and BasicEnemy. I created a for loop to make five different enemies but the collision detection doesn't get called on any of the enemies that were created from the for loop. The collision only works with the one BasicEnemy object. Why isn't collision function being called for all of the enemies inside the array? Thank you.

Sketch.js

```
var snake;
var food;
var basicEnemy;
var scl = 20;
var enemies = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 500);
  snake = new Snake();
  basicEnemy = new BasicEnemy();

  //** CREATE FIVE ENEMIES **
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    enemies[i] = new BasicEnemy();
  } 
}

  // **FUNCTION WHEN SNAKE HITS ENEMY**
  function collision() {
    console.log("hit!");
  }

  function draw() {
    background(51);

    //Draw snake 
    snake.update();
    snake.show();

    //Draw basicEnemy
    basicEnemy.update();
    basicEnemy.show();

    //** LOOP THROUGH ENEMIES AND UPDATE AND SHOW ** 
    for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
     enemies[i].show();
     enemies[i].update();

     if (enemies[i].hits(snake)) {
      collision();
     }
  }
}

  function keyPressed() {
 if (keyCode === UP_ARROW){
   snake.dir(0, -1);
 } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
   snake.dir(0, 1);
 } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
   snake.dir(-1 , 0);
 } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
   snake.dir(1 , 0);
 }
}
```

BasicEnemy.js

```
function BasicEnemy() {
  this.x = random(700);
  this.y = random(700);
  this.velX = 15;
  this.velY = 15;
}

//** FUNCTION TO CHECK IF ENEMY AND SNAKE ARE IN THE SAME LOCATION **
this.hits = function (pos) {
  var = d = dist(this.x, this.y, pos.x, pos.y);
   if(d < 1) {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
}

this.show = function () {
  fill(255, 0, 100);
  rect(this.x, this.y, scl, scl);
}
```

Snake.js

```
 function Snake() {
   this.x = 0;
   this.y = 0;
   this.xspeed = 1;
   this.yspeed = 0;

   this.update = function() {
     this.x = this.x + this.xspeed * scl;
     this.y = this.y + this.yspeed * scl;

     this.x = constrain(this.x, 0, width - scl);
     this.y = constrain(this.y, 0, height - scl);
  }

  this.show = function() {
    fill(255);
    rect(this.x, this.y, scl, scl);
  }

  this.dir = function (x , y) {
    this.xspeed = x;
    this.yspeed = y;
 }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `return d < 1;` instead of the 2 ifs

Comment: thanks, i will change it.

Comment: In the future please post a [mcve] instead of your entire project.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're essentially checking for the distance between the top left corners of the snake and the enemy, this'll only return true, if they completely overlap.

Use an AABB collision detection instead:

```
return this.x + scl >= pos.x && this.x <= pos.x + scl && this.y + scl >= pos.y && this.y <= pos.y + scl;
```

This returns true, if the first rectangle contains the second rectangle.

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection#Axis-Aligned_Bounding_Box):

> One of the simpler forms of collision detection is between two rectangles that are axis aligned — meaning no rotation. The algorithm works by ensuring there is no gap between any of the 4 sides of the rectangles. Any gap means a collision does not exist.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it would be great if you could explain why this code works.

Comment: am i suppose to put that code you posted inside of hits function?

Comment: same thing happen. hits function gets called only when i hit the basicEnemy object and not the rest of the enemies created from the for loop

Comment: oh wow. i figured out why hits function wasn't being called on the basicEnemy object. All i did was make a separate if statement for basicEnemy object. I wrote if (snake.intersects(basicEnemy)){console.log("hit); so now i have two if statements for both enemies array and basicEnemy